# Run Fabric task with Celery

Tags: python, celery, fabric

I need to use Celery to schedule a Fabric task on a set of hosts.

My code is:

**tasks.py**

```
from fabric_tasks import poll
from api.client import APIClient as client
from celery import Celery
celery = Celery(broker='redis://')

@celery.task
def poll_all():
  actions = client().get_actions(status='SCHEDULED)
  ids = [a['id'] for a in actions]
  execute(poll, ids, hosts=hosts)

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'every-5-second': {
        'task': 'tasks.poll_all',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=5),
    },
}
```

**celery -A tasks.celery -B -l info**
The task fail with the following exception:

```
[2016-12-11 17:54:07,928: ERROR/PoolWorker-3] Task tasks.poll_actions[7b26a083-b450-4a90-8971-97f3dd2f4f5d] raised unexpected: AttributeError("'Process' object has no attribute '_authkey'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ocervell/.virtualenvs/ndc-v3.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 367, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ocervell/.virtualenvs/ndc-v3.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 622, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ocervell/Drive/workspace/ccc/svn/build-support/branches/development-ocervell/modules/ndc/v3.3/tasks.py", line 44, in poll_all
    return execute(poll, 'ls', hosts=hosts)
  File "/Users/ocervell/.virtualenvs/ndc-v3.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 387, in execute
    multiprocessing
  File "/Users/ocervell/.virtualenvs/ndc-v3.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 269, in _execute
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=inner, kwargs=kwarg_dict)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 98, in __init__
    self._authkey = _current_process._authkey
AttributeError: 'Process' object has no attribute '_authkey'
```

**Temporary fix**

The following hack put in **tasks.py** helped me fix this bug (essentially it sets the attributes that caused the AttributeError exception):

```
from celery.signals import worker_process_init

@worker_process_init.connect
def fix_multiprocessing(**kwargs):
    from multiprocessing import current_process
    keys = {
      '_authkey': '',
      '_daemonic': False,
      '_tempdir': ''
    }
    for k, v in keys.items():
        try:
            getattr(current_process(), k)
        except AttributeError:
            setattr(current_process(), k, v)
```

**Related:**

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1709

[Python multiprocessing job to Celery task but AttributeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674950/python-multiprocessing-job-to-celery-task-but-attributeerror)

**Alternatives ?**

I was wondering if there is a better way for Celery to schedule Fabric tasks without writing dirty hacks around `multiprocessing` library ?